# Getting <LoadError: no such file to load -- factory_girl> with Rails 3 and factory_girl_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec2

I know I'm missing something fundamental, but I'm at a lost. After looking at the factory_girl site, I've installed the factory_girl_rails gem in Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'webrat'
    gem 'rspec'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
    gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
end
```

When I run "bundle install" I see both the factory_girl_rails gem and the dependent-Upon factory_girl gem get installed.

However, after creating my factory file and putting it in the spec/support directory:

```
require 'factory_girl'

Factory.define :user do |u|
    user.name                   "Example User"
    user.email                  "user@example.com"
    user.password               "foobar"
    user.password_confirmation  "foobar"
end
```

when I run rspec, I get the message LoadError: no such file to load -- factory_girl

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `require` statement is ... er ... required?

Comment: I put it there because I was getting uninitialized constant Factory. But  you are correct that it isn't required. Looking into the factory_girl_rails code, they are setting up the load order based on factories no longer being in the support directory. So I moved it out and got rid of that error finally. Then it only took me another long stretch to notice that my factory definition is using 'user' inside the block instead of 'u'. ~sigh~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the

```
require 'factory_girl'
```

in your "spec/spec_helper.rb" file? That's where it should go, generally.